# Android JSON API for wordpress taking too long to fetch data

Tags: android, json, wordpress

I have been working on getting data from JSON API for wordpress from https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

I have used the follwing to fetch data. Everything is working fine except that it is taking about 30 seconds to load data on to the tabview.

```
try {

            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);

            int count = (jObj.getInt("count_total"));


            JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("posts");



            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Year: " + date2.substring(0, 4) + "Hour: " + date2.substring(11, 13), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hour: "+date2.substring(11,13),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONArray jArray2 = json_data.getJSONArray("categories");
                JSONObject json_data2 = jArray2.getJSONObject(0);


                DataFish fishData = new DataFish();
                fishData.fishImage = json_data.getString("thumbnail");

                fishData.fishName = json_data.optString("title", "N/A");

                String comment = json_data.optString("comment_count", "0");
                fishData.comment = comment;
                 //fishData.fishName ="Title";

                //  fishData.sizeName = json_data.getString("size_name");
                String category_array = json_data2.optString("title", "N/A");


                fishData.sizeName = category_array;
                fishData.price = 10;
                fishData.url =
                        json_data.optString("url", "N/A");
                data.add(fishData);


            }
}
```

Any other way to fetch data faster so that user need not wait for awful 25-30 seconds to load data?

Comment: how many post are you getting from wp?

Comment: @PabloCegarra Only 5 posts at a time

Comment: and the delay time is parsing the json or requesting the data?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the new and highly used library for JSON or xml api integration or data convert library.

```
// retrofit, gson
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

and also see this link it help you that how to implement or use this

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/